# How to easily deal with situation when your Github pull request is merged with rebase?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

When contributing on Github I often end up in situation where person merging my pull request will merge with rebase. By doing that now my repository is effectively stuck as a "fork". Here is image showing the graph of how tree looks after rebase:

[image: git changes merged with git rebase]

The problem is that now my `origin\master` and `origin\HEAD` are outside of path of `source_repository\master`. What I've been doing so far is:

1. Delete my repository and just again fork from `source_repository`. Then I clone that new repository locally and everything is fine
2. I can change my `origin\HEAD` to another branch that's in path of rebase. Then delete `origin\master` and recreate it to point new HEAD. Finally switch `origin\HEAD` to point to new `origin\master`.

Both of these options seem too complicated, and it seems there must be easier way. What is it?

Comment: If you rebase locally, you will probably find that git will automatically see that "My pull req" on `master` and `origin/master` are the same and will leave you with just one instance of the commit.

Comment: @Mort yeah you are right... my local rebase works. But the problem would arise when I try `git push` to `origin`. That failed saying that I first need to pull changes... but doing that results in merge. What I effectively needed was ability to execute `git push --force` after local rebase.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that tool I am using (SourceTree) is not exposing `git push --force` by default. It seems they wanted to "protect users from themselves" as seen in this support case: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-do-I-perform-a-forced-push-push-f-from-SourceTree/qaq-p/257351

Luckily this option is now implemented, only you need to enable it by going `Tools -> Options -> Git -> Enable Force Push`.

Once you have that option you can `rebase` your local master and then `push --force` to get your `origin\master` on new path.

[image]